# Issues with BufferedWaveProvider

Tags: c#, .net, audio, buffer, naudio

I've been wracking my brain at this for awhile now. I've looked all over on SO already and I'm not finding any answers to my problem here. What I'm attempting to accomplish is a function that will allow my to select an input card for a microphone and output card to go to a radio. This code works on the initial try, but once i stop "Transmitting" you can hear what sounds like a doubled up audio stream and it becomes laggy and eventually crashes with a buffer full exception. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

```
        public WaveOutEvent outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent() { DeviceNumber = -1 };
        public WaveInEvent inputDevice = new WaveInEvent() { DeviceNumber = -1 };
        public bool transmit = false;
        public bool markerActive = false;
        public bool alert1Active = false;
    
        public SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
        public string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        private BufferedWaveProvider bufferedWaveProvider;
        
        public string keyTransmitter()
        {
            
            string label;
            if (transmit)
            {
                transmit = false;
                port.DtrEnable = false;
                port.RtsEnable = false;
                label = "Transmit";
                bufferedWaveProvider.ClearBuffer();
                
                inputDevice.StopRecording();
                inputDevice.Dispose();

                outputDevice.Dispose();
                outputDevice.Stop();
                
               
            }
            else
            {
                transmit = true;
                port.DtrEnable = true;
                port.RtsEnable = true;
                label = "Transmitting";
             
                bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(inputDevice.WaveFormat);
                inputDevice.DataAvailable += OnDataAvailable;
                inputDevice.StartRecording();

                outputDevice.Init(bufferedWaveProvider);
                outputDevice.Play();
            


            }

            return label;
        }

        public void OnDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs args)
        {
            bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(args.Buffer, 0, args.BytesRecorded);
            //bufferedWaveProvider.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;
 
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A BufferedWaveProvider has a size limit, so it must be changed if it wants more audio, but it will eventually overload, so we'll use "DiscardOnBufferOverflow", so here's the code example:

NOTE: if you are using a single reproduction, it is not necessary to change BufferedWaveProvider to a new one.

```
BufferedWaveProvider waveChannel = new BufferedWaveProvider(INFO HERE);
waveChannel.BufferDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0); //BufferDuration, 1 minute
waveChannel.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true; //The name says
```

It will not be necessary to use "init" or "play" again, because BufferedWaveProvider, when not buffered, it generates silence for WaveOut

English from google translator

Comment: That didn't answer my question very well at all.

Comment: Have you tried to leave "DiscardOnBufferOverflow" active and use "WaveOut" and "WaveIn" instead of "WaveOutEvent" and "WaveInEvent"?
 The developer recommends using them for greater compatibility in these cases. 
 I also noticed that you are constantly recreating the "bufferedWave Provider", this is not necessary, just change the "WaveFormat" if it is changed.

Comment: As for the delay of reproduction, there will always be, but it can be reduced in the property "BufferMilliseconds" of "WaveIn", if reducing the milliseconds will reduce the wait for new buffers, but that has some negative points, I use naudio to make udp streaming , 20 milliseconds seems ideal, the recommended is between 50 and 100